# Check url and filter content based on ID value detected

Tags: jquery

Logic here: if the url has !#10 or !#20 or !#30, check id value of li. Then filter div "contentEle" based on li id value. "contentEle" id & li id matches, filter.

My script: filter is working. But add class selected not working. It selects last element in the container and filtering that id and display.

**HTML**

http://localhost:1234/test/index.html#!id10

```
<ul>
    <li class="slist selected" id="id1"><a href="#!id10">Test1/a></li>
    <li class="slist" id="id2"><a href="#!id20">Test2</a></li>
    <li class="slist" id="id3"><a href="#!id30">Test3/a></li>
</ul>


<div class="content specials">
    <div class="contentEle id1">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/265/149/sports/" alt="">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...</div>       
    </div>
    <div class="contentEle id2">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/265/149/sports/" alt="">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...</div>       
    </div>
    <div class="contentEle id1">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/265/149/sports/" alt="">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...</div>       
    </div>
    <div class="contentEle id2">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/265/149/sports/" alt="">
            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...</div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var $els = $('.content div.contentEle').hide(),
    $curr = $();

$('ul li').each(function(i)
{
    var listID = "#!" + window.location.href.split("!")[1];
    if ($('ul li a[href="' + listID + '"]').length) {   
        console.log(listID); 
        $('.slist.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $curr = $els.filter('.' + this.id).hide();
        $curr.slice(0, 6).show();
        $els.not($curr).hide();  
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```js
var $els = $('.content div.contentEle').hide(),
  hash = '!id10' //could be window.location.hash.replace(/^#/, '')
;

if (hash) {
  var $a = $('.slist a[href="#' + hash + '"]'),
    $li;
  if ($a.length) {
    $li = $a.parent().addClass('selected');
    $li.siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $els.filter('.' + $li.attr('id')).show()
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="slist selected" id="id1"><a href="#!id10">Test1</a></li>
  <li class="slist" id="id2"><a href="#!id20">Test2</a></li>
  <li class="slist" id="id3"><a href="#!id30">Test3</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="content specials">
  <div class="contentEle id1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/265/149/sports/" alt="" />
    <div class="text">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentEle id2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/265/149/food/" alt="" />
    <div class="text">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentEle id1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/265/149/sports/" alt="" />
    <div class="text">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentEle id3">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/265/149/food/" alt="" />
    <div class="text">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```